# Flask Docker container not connecting to another Postgres docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, flask

So I built an app on my home machine and it worked perfectly. Unfortunately moving the configuration of three docker containers where one flask container accesses another postgres server fails. I am accessing the postgres container using psycopg2 using a hostname. The issue has been isolated to the connecting between one docker container to the next as I can access the server itself, the backend works if it doesn't have to access to the server, but it fails when it does. So heres the config I have currently (I am happy to send any config needed but in the interest of not sending an infinite amount Ill start with just docker compose):

Here is my docker compose that works on a intel macbook pro with docker compose v2.0.0 but doesnt work on an ampere oracle vm with docker compose v2.1.1

```
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.api
    # image: react-flask-app-api
    depends_on:
      - postgres_real
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    links:
      - postgres_real:postgres_real
    networks:
      - backend
  client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.client
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    links:
      - backend:backend
    networks:
      - backend
  postgres_real:
    container_name: postgres_real
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - "5432"
    networks:
      - backend
networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

EDIT:
So I would like to simplify my question further.
After more testing, curl commands and attempting to forward requests through nginx using the following configuration

```
# nginx configuration for Docker

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
    }

    location /static {
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend:5000;
    }
}
```

I have found that on a oracle server, the docker subnet does not actually work in that it is not able to make a request from one docker container to another. I am not sure what is needed so here are the probable required configs:

Config of my docker network that works on my personal machine but not on the server

```
   {
        "Name": "congress_backend",
        "Id": "b484525801f859d3f38b59ea3b74baa6214e12acf3fcdf72e2115ee1a7c7c192",
        "Created": "2022-12-24T07:50:54.96602112Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.23.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.23.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "188de200ef405c8e1b859c57fcecda64c7b951ca38cd17d92db301b2b63677a7": {
                "Name": "congress-client-1",
                "EndpointID": "a170d1a21231a17c3c367e10dc0daaf56281bb9051161cae67e6e696c9f44ade",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "5fae87555e453a2d6e6d2d080d1c128932a90dc2e71c75b31a82b1a365713497": {
                "Name": "congress-backend-1",
                "EndpointID": "63801907b9c92b6ac318bbe6cf69e6b08a5f0b82e9fcb1590977116fce8f4690",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "73f9ece1a79e94e7442d01823f181e244a952f2bf3fde2e205e4c95a8aa74429": {
                "Name": "postgres_real",
                "EndpointID": "3d074029759e069f66519a0f3308d50801d1e1c09a48b1fa88870533980f6e45",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "backend",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "congress",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.1.1"
        }
    }
```

And here is my Iptables config for IPV4
rulesv4:

```
# CLOUD_IMG: This file was created/modified by the Cloud Image build process
# iptables configuration for Oracle Cloud Infrastructure

# See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure
# documentation for security impact of modifying or removing these rule

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [463:49013]
:InstanceServices - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j InstanceServices
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.2/32 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 3260 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.2.0/24 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 3260 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.4.0/24 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 3260 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.5.0/24 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 3260 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.3/32 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 69 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p udp --dport 123 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.0/16 -p tcp -m tcp -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.0/16 -p udp -m udp -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT
```

My application is configured using a flask application with something like this

```
@app.route('/api/bill/<bill_slug>')
def bill_data(bill_slug):
    data = get_bill_data(bill_slug.upper())
    return jsonify(data)
# get bill data uses psycopg2 like this:
conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host=os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
            database=os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
            user=os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
            password=os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD')
        )
# where DB_HOST is in this format postgresql://user:password@postgres_real:5432/database_name
```

if I try a curl command on something that just returns the time it works but if I try something similar like

```
curl 0.0.0.0:5000/api/bill/Hello
```

it returns with

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

internally in docker it errors as

```
[2022-12-24 16:19:37 +0000] [8] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:11)
[2022-12-24 16:19:38 +0000] [8] [WARNING] Worker with pid 11 was terminated due to signal 9
[2022-12-24 16:19:38 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
```

Comment: You need to show a minimal, complete example of the application code that demonstrates the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What's the host name?  Where do you configure it?  What's the error message?  If you're interested in keeping the question length down even with these details, you can remove unnecessary parts of your Compose file (`networks:`, `container_name:`, the `client` container) as part of constructing your [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is wondering how this is solved, I recommend checking out your iptables configuration and seeing if there is a legacy configuration as well. In my case, the legacy iptables configuration blocked all forwarding. After turning this off, docker worked perfectly.